# Error while installing GNU Octave packages

Tags: installation, octave

I want to install the GNU Octave optim package, but I keep receiving errors in the process. Apparently I need to install some other packages first, one of which is the general package. However, when I try to, I receive this error:

```
octave:17> pkg install general-1.3.2.tar.gz
make: /usr/bin/mkoctfile: Command not found
make: *** [__exit__.oct] Error 127
'make' returned the following error: make: Entering directory `/tmp/oct-CGIPo9/general/src'
/usr/bin/mkoctfile __exit__.cc
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/oct-CGIPo9/general/src'
error: called from `pkg>configure_make' in file /usr/share/octave/3.6.1/m/pkg/pkg.m near line 1391, column 9
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.1/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 834, column 5
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.1/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 383, column 9
```

Comment: Could you show the sequence of commands that you are entering?

Comment: How did you install octave? `make` is complaining about missing `/usr/bin/mkoctfile`.

Comment: Also, from where have you downloaded the source? (link it)

Comment: The command I'm using is pkg install <filename>. I installed it from the repositories. The packages were dowloaded from the official Octave Sourceforge's site: http://octave.sourceforge.net/general/index.html

Comment: I installed it from the picasso/octave repositoy, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should be solved with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install octave-pkg-dev
```

It installs the missing `mkoctfile` program.

Comment: when I did this it reverted or un-installed octave 3.6.4 and installed Octave 3.2.4... not good!